# Fractal Project Structure with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, fractals

Is it possible (and reasonable) to use a fractal based project structure with ASP.Net MVC?  If so, would love to see some examples.

Comment: You can have areas that group controllers/models/views (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx). I am not sure if this is enough "fractal" for you.